# ASIO crashing under Windows 8 when the application is 64-bit and compiled using MSVC2012 or MSVC2013

Tags: windows, visual-c++, audio, windows-8, asio

So I have an interesting huge trouble... I downloaded newest ASIO SDK, compiled the host sample and it is crashing (or doing nonsense...) with several ASIO drivers if ALL of these conditions are met:

```
1) Compiled using MSVC2012 or MSVC2013 (MSVC2005 is fine)
2) 64-bit build (32-bit is fine)
3) Run on Windows 8 (Windows 7 are fine)
```

Any ideas what the hell is wrong there?

Comment: Attach a debugger and find out.

Comment: :D Well I spent a day doing that... it's crashing in the driver... but why not all drivers? Why not when compiled with MSVC2005?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution - linker option:

/DYNAMICBASE:NO

It seems that there is bug in ASIO drivers making it cause problems with address above 32-bit, so without this option Windows 8 may place the app anywhere in the address space (probably hack protection) and whoops...